# Django and Angular routing

Tags: angularjs, django

We are using Django as backend and Angular as front end and templating. I am doing the front end part.

When I designed the UI the url was

```
xxx/dashboard.html#/
```

but while intergeating I get

```
xxx/dashboard/#/
```

so whats the difference.

Also my routeprovider in Angular is throwing 404 error

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/dash_home.html',
    controller: 'dashController'
})
```

My Html

```
<!doctype html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    ....        
</head>
<body ng-app="gb_dash">
{% block content %}
    <div class="fullWidth">
        <div ng-view>...
```

My app structure

```
>apps
>deployment
...
...
>static
    >bower_components
    ...
    ...
    >js
        dash.js //angular_app
>templates
    >pages
        dash_home.html
    dashboard.html
```

I am getting error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/templates/pages/dash_home.html 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Where am i mistaking. I tried html5mode, then no error showing but still the template didnt load. Or is there backend mistake?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you use

```
xxx/dashboard.html#/
```

then in the route provider

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '#/pages/dash_home.html',
    controller: 'dashController'
})
```

It will look for the # and then attach the url with it.

Comment: Actually I am the front end developer. The basic route i was given is preceded with / before #. I'll ask my backend team. Also If i use # in the templateUrl, Multiple pages are loading in the same page.

Comment: okay, can you give an example of the working url that loads the page?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/gb_front/dashboard.html#/  This is what is suppose to get but i am receiving  http://localhost:8000/testschool/dashboard/#/  . never mind the domain that is after django implementation.